# Include error.Functions already declared

Tags: c++, include, header-files

I've read a lot for this problem ,but I haven't found a proper solution.
So i have 4 files:

```
includes.h - which contains all libraries I need in other files + some global functions
cities.h - which contains declarations of  2 classes
cities.cpp - which contains definitions of the 2 classes in cities.h
source.cpp - where is the main functon
```

And I have(and need) these includes

```
//cities.h
#include "includes.h"

//cities.cpp
#include "cities.h"

//source.cpp
#include "cities.h"
```

I've tried almost all combinations of `#ifndef` in all of the files and the program continues to give me the same error: `function_X already declared in cities.obj`.And this error repeats for all functions in "includes.h".
Please help me.This makes me a lot of headaches.

Comment: Does `includes.h` `#include` `cities.h`?

Comment: Do any of the headers define (rather than declare) functions?

Comment: if you have a function defined in `cities.h` add `inline` to stop `multiple definitions error`. Also show use the exact error, it will help use debug it faster.

Comment: No,headers.h doesn't include cities.h.
Only in includes.h I have definitions of functions,but that wasn't a problem until I've made a second cpp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've described in the comments, you have function definitions in your `includes.h` header file. When this is included in multiple implementation files, you end up with multiple definitions of those functions in your program. This breaks the *one definition rule*. You should simply declare functions in `includes.h` and move their definitions into a `includes.cpp` file.

Something like this:

```
// includes.h

void foo();
int bar(int);


// includes.cpp

void foo() {
  // implementation
}

int bar(int x) {
  // implementation
}
```

I'm going to try and preempt a question that typically follows this answer. No, your include guards (`#ifndef ...`) are not meant to prevent this. They only prevent a header being included multiple times in a *single* translation unit. You are including the header in multiple translation units, which an include guard does not stop.

Answer (score 0):

On top of what @sftrabbit said, If you are making a headers only library where you need to define the functions in the the header file this is possible with the keyword `inline`.

```
// includes.h
inline void foo() {
    // implementation
}

inline int bar(int x) {
    // implementation
}
```

This use of `inline` is not to be mistaken with its other use as a compiler suggestion to `inline` the function call.